# How to incrementing each of the score TextViews?

Tags: android

I'm making an scoreboard and want to keep track of the total score.
If i fill a random number in both textviews, i want a sum of the 2 numbers as a total in the totalscore. how do i do that. in my previous question i had this code as an answer but they said i must incrementing each of the score TextViews and hook up each of the TextViews with a TextWatcher. **How to incrementing each of the score TextViews?**

[image]

```
    final TextView TotalScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Total);
    final EditText One = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Score1);
    final EditText Two = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Score2);

    TotalSore.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            int Score1 = Integer.parseInt((String) One.getText().toString());
            int Score2 = Integer.parseInt((String) Two.getText().toString());

            TotalScore.setText(String.valueOf(Score1 + Score2));
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Comment: `Integer.parseInt((String) One.getText().toString());` - there's no point casting a `String` to a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you could increment One:

```
String oneText = One.getText().toString();
int oneScore = Integer.parseInt(oneText);
++oneScore;
One.setText(oneScore+"");
```

You can do the same for `Two`

***UPDATE***:

If you want to update the score total, you should apply the `TextWatcher` to both `One` and `Two`.

```
class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        int Score1 = Integer.parseInt((String) One.getText().toString());
        int Score2 = Integer.parseInt((String) Two.getText().toString());

        TotalScore.setText(String.valueOf(Score1 + Score2));
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}

One.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher());
Two.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher());
```

Comment: do i just add the code under the code i already have or do i have to change same of my code with that you gave me?
and if i must change something what do i need to change?

Comment: Assuming that One and Two already have numbers in them, then the code should be able to run from where ever it is that you want to increment their values.  Perhaps in an onClick() method somewhere...

Comment: i changed this code:
 
**int Score1 = Integer.parseInt((String) One.getText().toString());
 int Score2 = Integer.parseInt((String) Two.getText().toString());**
 
to:
 
 **String one = One.getText().toString();
 int Score1 = Integer.parseInt(one);
 ++Score1;
 One.setText(Score1+"");
                
 String two = Two.getText().toString();
 int Score2 = Integer.parseInt(two);
 ++Score2;
 Two.setText(Score2+"");**

but when i put a number in the two textviews, nothing happens.
i want them to sum up and show an result in the total score.

Comment: when i want to fill in a number the app stops unexpectedly

Comment: You will have to edit your question to post updated code and the stacktrace.

Comment: There is an edit link at the bottom of your question.  Click and update!